# Scrappy crawl error in virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, virtualenvwrapper

Tried the [Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), but cannot run the crawling script:

`scrapy crawl quotes`

The error I get:

`-bash: /home/szendrei/.virtualenvs/scrapy-projects/bin/scrapy: No such file or directory`

I'm under a virtual environment (created with virtualenvwrapper), and Python version 3.8. Scrapy installed with pip3 in the virtual environment. `which scrapy` shows nothing, `pip3 show scrapy` says:

```
Name: Scrapy
Version: 2.7.1
Summary: A high-level Web Crawling and Web Scraping framework
Home-page: https://scrapy.org
Author: Scrapy developers
Author-email:
License: BSD
Location: /home/szendrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: cryptography, cssselect, itemadapter, itemloaders, lxml, packaging, parsel, protego, PyDispatcher, pyOpenSSL, queuelib, service-identity, setuptools, tldextract, Twisted, w3lib, zope.interface
Required-by:
```

`scrapy startproject tutorial` worked just fine.

Tried to reinstall, but requirements already satisfied.

What could be the solution?

Comment: what does `which python3` say?

Comment: ```/usr/bin/python3```

Answer (score 0):

Still don't konw how, but I managed to solve the problem. Uninstalled scrapy with `pip3 uninstall scarpy`, deleted the folders that have been created before for the project, and installed again. Now it works.